# how to add footer on invoice pdf magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, create-invoice, invoice-pdf

I am using magento 2.1.
I want to add some "term & condition" at the bottom of customer invoice.
How can I add a Custom footer on PDF invoice that is generated in Magento2?

Can anyone explain me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

*Override **invoice php** file for invoice pdf customization,*
**Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice,**

```
class Invoicepdf extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice{
     public function getPdf($invoices = [])
        {       
            //custom code of getpdf

                //add new footer section this is our custom code function...
                $this->_drawFooter($page);   

             $this->_afterGetPdf();
             return $pdf;
        }

        protected function _drawFooter(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
        {
            $this->y =50;    
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(1, 1, 1));
            $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(60, $this->y, 510, $this->y -30);

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
            $page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 7);
            $this->y -=10;
            $page->drawText("Company name", 70, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText("Tel: +123 456 676", 230, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText("Registered in Countryname", 430, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

        }
}
```

> Page size can be retrieved from a page object's get widht and height function,
>   using $page object:

**//start with zend_pdf method of zend frameworks,**

```
$pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
$this->_setPdf($pdf);
```

**//create new page in pdf**

```
$page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
```

**//set color**

```
$page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

**//set font**

```
$page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 8);
```

**//set stye for pdf,**

```
$style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
```

**//set bold font**

```
$this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

$page->drawText($title, 225, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

**//get page widht**

```
$width  = $page->getWidth(); //width for A4 page, 595
```

**//get page height**

```
$height = $page->getHeight(); //Height for A4 page,842
```

Comment: What is the second parameter of 'drawText()'? How does one glean the correct value?

Comment: Nevermind I actually needed to just edit the frontend template, not the pdf,
'vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/info.phtml'